# Excel macro adjust cell height

Tags: vba, excel

My script moves data to excel template. Codewords is changed for relevant info. [image: template]

All works well if TPLNR and AUFNR is filled. The cell is two rows in height. But if i leave AUFNR or TPLNR blank - cell height not ajusted. This is macro used to fill and adjust every row in table.

```
Sub Mac1()
'
' Mac1 
'
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 12

'
    Do While Range("L" & i).Value <> "THE END"

        If Range("L" & i).Value = "M" Then
        ...            
        ElseIf Range("L" & i).Value = "T" Then

        Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Orientation = 0
            .WrapText = True
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = True
        End With
        Selection.Merge
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = True
        End With

        Selection.Font.Italic = True

        End If


        i = i + 1

    Loop

     Call AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight

     Columns("L:L").Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
Sub AutoFitMergedCellRowHeight()
    Dim CurrentRowHeight As Single, MergedCellRgWidth As Single
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Dim ActiveCellWidth As Single, PossNewRowHeight As Single
    Dim StartCell As Range, c As Range, MergeRng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim a() As String, isect As Range, i


'Take a note of current active cell
Set StartCell = ActiveCell

'Create an array of merged cell addresses that have wrapped text
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If c.MergeCells Then
    With c.MergeArea
    If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
        If MergeRng Is Nothing Then
            Set MergeRng = c.MergeArea
            ReDim a(0)
            a(0) = c.MergeArea.Address
        Else
        Set isect = Intersect(c, MergeRng)
            If isect Is Nothing Then
                Set MergeRng = Union(MergeRng, c.MergeArea)
                ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
                a(UBound(a)) = c.MergeArea.Address
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End With
End If
Next c


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop thru merged cells
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
Range(a(i)).Select
      With ActiveCell.MergeArea
            If .Rows.Count = 1 And .WrapText = True Then
                'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                CurrentRowHeight = .RowHeight
                ActiveCellWidth = ActiveCell.ColumnWidth
                For Each CurrCell In Selection
                    MergedCellRgWidth = CurrCell.ColumnWidth + MergedCellRgWidth
                Next
                .MergeCells = False
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergedCellRgWidth
                .EntireRow.AutoFit
                PossNewRowHeight = .RowHeight
                .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = ActiveCellWidth
                .MergeCells = True
                .RowHeight = IIf(CurrentRowHeight > PossNewRowHeight, _
                  CurrentRowHeight, PossNewRowHeight)
            End If
        End With
MergedCellRgWidth = 0
Next i

StartCell.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Clean up
Set CurrCell = Nothing
Set StartCell = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
Set MergeRng = Nothing
Set Cell = Nothing

End Sub
```

What could i do to get rows after 12 to look like it intended to? With 1x height. [image: Result]

Comment: Would it work if you remove `.EntireRow.AutoFit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the rows equal size is quite a standard VBA task.

Just try to put this logic away from your code. The only 3 things you should know is the starting row, the ending row and the size. Thus, you may be able to do it quite well. In the code below change the parameters of     `Call AllRowsAreEqual(4, 10, 35)` in order to make it work for you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AllRowsAreEqual(lngStartRow As Long, lngEndRow As Long, lngSize)

    Dim lngCounter  As Long

    For lngCounter = lngStartRow To lngEndRow
        Cells(lngCounter, 1).RowHeight = lngSize
        'Debug.Print lngCounter 
    Next lngCounter

End Sub

Public Sub Main()

    Call AllRowsAreEqual(4, 10, 35)

End Sub
```

Comment: It might be worth taking out the debug.print for a sub that you aren't troubleshooting to keep the pane clear.